# Would there ever be a good reason to replace a clustered index with a unique non-clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I am cleaning up a database and there are performance issues with heavy traffic. Reading and writing. But the heavy traffic is condensce to a few days annually.

I suspect one problem is a lot of heavily-used tables don't have a clustered index. But they do have a primary key and a unique, non-clustered index tied to it that is just on the primary key (no includes).

Is this a beneficial approach anytime?

My guess is someone thought it would be faster if the db didn't have to insert all the columns from a clustered index (I wouldn't do this ever myself so I don't know the madness behind the method).

I am starting the task of applying clustered indexes to these tables, but wanted to survey smarter minds before I got too far to see if there is a scenario where a strategy like this would help?

I would think the loss of connections to the clustered index would outweigh any gain this might have?

Comment: Are you saying that the index supporting the primary key is nonclustered? Because that's very unusual. Usually, the primary key is also the clustered index, and that may or may not be optimal, but that's another matter.

Comment: Yes. There is a field designated as a primary key. There is a unique nonclustered index defined on that field (and only that field). It is the only index on the table. I know it's odd. I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel fairly confident in saying that no, this is not a beneficial approach, ever. If a table has only nonclustered indexes, it's a heap table, and aside from bulk insert operations, there is no good reason for having a heap table. That's not just me talking, that's [Microsoft's opinion as well](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917672.aspx).

I have maintained a big warehouse where it was a good idea to not have a primary key at all (because the index for it took up a huge amount of space without being used), but only a unique clustered index on a `DATETIME` plus an `ID`. But you'll note that, primary key or not, it did have a clustered index, because not having one is just a bad idea.

Comment: Well, aside for the valid reason you did give, a huge number of inserts with very few, if any, reads.

Comment: @Steve: all scenarios I can think of would involve using that table as a staging source for something else, but you're right that that isn't necessarily only bulk inserts. For example, you could have a table that is used exclusively for logging events that are never queried, except at the end of the day when you copy them to a warehouse.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with you.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you have a candidate key, then use it as clustered index. A unique, non-clustered index can be used for key look-ups and to guarantee uniqueness. A clustered index will be used for that, and in addition for range scans and for sort guarantees.

When the heavy traffic is condensed to 'a few days', this is indicative of time series, where queries ask for recent *ranges*: totals and other aggregates for today, for last day, for last week etc. Making the table organized by the time makes all these queries work w/o having to scan the entire table, end-tot-end.

A primary key does not have to match the clustered index. The primary key is a logical concept, useful for modeling the data and enforcing referential integrity in a primary/foreign key relationship (strictly speaking the foreign key can reference *any* column(s), but most often it references the primary key).

The clustered index will define the physical layout, is driven by practical considerations around most frequent queries, type of range scans present, and size-of-key trade-offs.

Adding a clustered index will likely change some access patterns and may introduce new deadlock possibilities, but frankly the chances are slim. Is usually *removing* a clustered index that adds deadlocks, not adding it.

Finally, I wouldn't worry too much about insert/update cost. Most applications have an overwhelming read-to-write ratio and having faster reads make the app feel much more responsive and more 'snappy'. Also the read improvement from having a usable index manifest as x100s times improvements (small range scan vs. table end-to-end scan) while write degradation manifests as fractional increase (e.g. write times increase by 10-15%), usually unnoticeable in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Inserts are much faster when you don't have a clustered index but by having a primary key, there is still a uniqueness. Therefore while a standard heap requires a query to search every record to find the one you want, a heap with a non-clustered primary key will stop after it finds the first result. While this is still slow, it is faster than nothing and if you are doing 1M inserts to 1 query, well worth it.

Log tables are a prime example where this is useful.

Comment: The article from Microsoft I linked has benchmarks, showing that a heap table is *slower* in almost all scenarios (inserting, updating, deleting), except for highly concurrent inserts. So you'll want to test extra carefully, because it definitely isn't true that a heap table will always give better insert performance, counter-intuitive as that may be (again, obviously not counting parallel bulk inserts).